# MAMP & MyPHPAdmin Incorrect Format Parameter

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mamp

I downloaded a database from our current host to open our site files locally and have attempted to import the database into my local `myphpadmin` server. It is showing only a max file size upload of 8,192 KiB. I am running `php` version 7.2.8 and have adjusted file size and parameters in the accompanying `php.ini` file for 7.2.8 but do not see any changes in `MyPHPAdmin`. I have done the following with no success:

1. Edited `php.ini`
2. Edited `config.inc.php`
3. Refreshed Servers
4. Upgraded `MAMP` to `MAMP Pro`
5. Even tried bypassing the code to offer a drop-down file source option to `MyPHPAdmin`

Nothing has worked and I am at a loss as all other solutions are for `XAMP` not `MAMP`. I can provide info just don't know what else needs to be known to offer guidance.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

Which php.ini file did you edit?

You should always:

1. Check the version of PHP (run PHPINFO)
2. Check on PHPINFO where is located the proper php.ini file.
3. Edit on proper php.ini file lines:

   ```
   upload_max_filesize=64M
   post_max_size=64M
   ```

For example instead of:

> /Applications/MAMP/apache/php7.1.22/conf/php.ini

you should edit:

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.22/php.ini

Comment: For MAMP too it works - https://huyhoa.net/en/fix-phpmyadmin-error-incorrect-format-parameter/